# How to find the usages of a Scala class'es constructor in IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, usability

Is there a possibility to find the usages of a Scala class'es constructor in IntelliJ?

When using "Find Usages" on such constructor, it also applies to every usage of the class'es signature (since the signature is shared between the class and its constructor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in IDEA(my version is 2020.2.4) `Find Usages Settings...`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think IDEA allows you to do it directly, but you can kind of achieve this by temporarily adding a new parameter, compiling and looking at errors (this will "find" pattern matches using this class as well).

Comment: That's too bad. Oh well, we all got our work-arounds :)